# How fast can we make a specific tr?

Tags: c, performance, io

I had to replace all the null bytes in a file with another character (I arbitrarily chose `@`), and was pretty surprised that `tr '\00' '@'` was about 1/4 the speed of `gzip`:

```
$ pv < lawl | gzip > /dev/null
^C13MiB 0:00:04 [28.5MiB/s] [====>                             ] 17% ETA 0:00:18
$ pv < lawl | tr '\00' '@' > /dev/null
^C58MiB 0:00:08 [7.28MiB/s] [==>                               ]  9% ETA 0:01:20
```

My real data file is 3GB gzipped and took 50 minutes to `tr`, and I'll actually need to do this on many such files, so it's not a completely academic problem. Note that reading from disk (a reasonably fast SSD here), or `pv`, isn't the bottleneck in either case; both `gzip` and `tr` are using 100% CPU, and `cat` is much faster:

```
$ pv < lawl | cat > /dev/null
 642MiB 0:00:00 [1.01GiB/s] [================================>] 100%
```

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\00') {
            putchar('@');
        } else {
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

compiled with `clang -O3` is somewhat faster:

```
$ pv < lawl | ./stupidtr > /dev/null
^C52MiB 0:00:06 [ 8.5MiB/s] [=>                                ]  8% ETA 0:01:0
```

Compiling with `gcc -O4 -mtune=native -march=native` (4.8.4) is comparable, maybe very slightly faster. Adding `-march=native` to clang (`Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)`) produces an identical binary.

This is presumably just because the generic processing code for replacements in `tr` is replaced with constants and the checks can be compiled down. The LLVM IR (`clang -S -O3 stupidtr.c`) looks pretty good.

I guess `gzip` must be faster because it's doing something SIMD instructions or something. Is it possible to get this up to `gzip` speeds?

Some specifications, if they're relevant:

- The file is a CSV; the null byte can only occur in a certain field, but some of the other fields are variable-length, so you can't just seek around arbitrarily. Most lines have a null byte in that field. I suppose this means you could do a [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) search for `,\00,`, if that'd help. Once you've found a null byte, it's also guaranteed that there can't be another one for a hundred bytes or so.
- A typical file is about 20 GiB uncompressed, but are bz2 compressed on disk, if that's relevant.
- You can parallelize if you want, though `gzip` does this with one so it shouldn't be necessary. I'll be running this either on a quad-core i7 running OSX or a two-vCPU cloud server running Linux.
- Both machines I might run on have 16GB of RAM.

Comment: You forgot to finish the sentence _Is it possible to get_ just before the specs at the end.

Comment: @xxbbcc Thanks, fixed. Nonlinear writing is hard. :)

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=20000 | pv | tr '\00' '@' > /dev/null`  (similar to your second case) proceeds at 322MB/s on my not-that-fancy notebook, fwiw.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I get 7 MiB/s (changing to `bs=1048576` since OSX's `dd` doesn't support the `1M` syntax). Presumably a buffering difference in the OSes...

Comment: `char ch` cannot correctly hold the value `EOF`: If `char` is unsigned by default, your code will never stop, otherwise if will mistakenly stop on `'\377'` also.

Comment: @chqrlie It's signed, as can be seen in the LLVM output...but yes, that means it dies stupidly on a weird input character. Switching it to `int` slows it down very slightly.

Comment: GNU coreutils `tr` 8.23 is really fast, too, on an input of all-zeros.  I get 1.2GiB/s on my 3.7GHz sandybridge Linux desktop (dual channel 1600MHz DDR3).  The translation loop is a byte-at-a-time table lookup.  (ran under gdb, hit ^c once it was running, then single-stepped until I got out of the i/o functions and into a loop.  (actually `fin` a few times to get out of functions...))  Anyway, it does `movzx edx, byte [rbx+rax]` / `movzx edx, byte [rdx+table]` / `mov [rbx+rax], dl`, `add rax, 1` / `cmp/ja`.  That avoids any branch mispredicts, and tr has to support an arbitrary mapping anyway.

Comment: IDK how your `tr` is so slow.  That's on OS X?  Maybe branch mispredicts?  But more likely, I/O buffering problems.  gzip almost certainly doesn't use SIMD; lossless compression tends not to be parallelizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining ideas from the various answers with some extra bithacks, here is an optimized version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE  16384
#define REPLACE_CHAR  '@'

int main(void) {
    /* define buffer as uint64_t to force alignment */
    /* make it one slot longer to allow for loop guard */
    uint64_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE/8 + 1];
    ssize_t size, chunk;
    uint64_t *p, *p_end;
    uint64_t rep8 = (uint8_t)REPLACE_CHAR * 0x0101010101010101ULL;

    while ((size = read(0, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0) {
        if (size < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) continue;
            fprintf(stderr, "read error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        p = buffer;
        p_end = p + ((size + 7) >> 3);
        *p_end = 0ULL; /* force a 0 at the end */
        for (;; p++) {
#define LOWBITS   0x0101010101010101ULL
#define HIGHBITS  0x8080808080808080ULL
            uint64_t m = ((*p - LOWBITS) & ~*p & HIGHBITS);
            if (m != 0) {
                if (p >= p_end) break;
                m |= m >> 1;
                m |= m >> 2;
                m |= m >> 4;
                *p |= m & rep8;
            }
        }
        for (unsigned char *pc = (unsigned char *)buffer;
             (chunk = write(1, pc, (size_t)size)) != size;
             pc += chunk, size -= chunk) {
            if (chunk < 0) {
                if (errno == EINTR) continue;
                fprintf(stderr, "write error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ~900 MiB/s with clang -O3. We've now moved well past the stage where this is the bottleneck. :)

Comment: @Dougal: 8.5 to 900, that's the kind of multiple I live for ;-)

Comment: Hey! No using ```sizeof``` without parentheses! [Where I come from](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/7/11/103), you get shot for doing that :p

Comment: @durka42: I usually recommend always using `()` even if they are redundant, but I don't shoot programmers for that.  For clarity, I should probably not use `sizeof` here at all.

Comment: @durka42: Ahh, another example of Linus being idiotic.  To take his example, `sizeof (x) + 1` is no less ambiguous than `sizeof x + 1`.  What you should write is `(sizeof x) + 1`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: the extra space in `sizeof (x)` is indeed confusing.  Linus is not being idiotic, he is being anal and idiomatic.  For the mere mortals who see `sizeof` as a function, `sizeof(x) + 1` is not ambiguous at all.  Coding styles are useful to make code readable for humans. Consistency is a key feature for readability.  Enforcing parentheses on `sizeof` is indeed more consistent.  Would you also remove redundant parentheses in `(x + 7) & ~7` ?

Comment: @chqrlie: The problem with `sizeof x + 1` is that people may not remember that `sizeof` has higher precedence than `+`.  The problem with `sizeof (x)+1` is... guess what... people may not remember that `sizeof` has higher precedence than `+`.  Only in `(sizeof x) + 1` do the parentheses make the parse clear.  It's not a matter of removing redundant parentheses, it's a matter of putting them where they do some good.

Comment: Interestingly, ICC13 [auto-vectorizes @Ben's simple loop (with `pcmpeqb` / `pblendvb`)](http://goo.gl/uXWPK1), but gcc/clang don't.  None of the three auto-vectorize your bit-hack, so it has a branch mispredict on every uint64_t that has a hit.  Still, if you're not building with ICC, your bithack is a big win.  Oh also, you're missing a close-paren in `while ((size = read(0, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) != 0) {`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use block reads and writes for speed.  (Even with a buffered I/O library like stdio.h, the cost of managing the buffer can be significant.)  Something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main( void )
{
    char buffer[16384];
    int size, i;
    while ((size = read(0, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0) {
        for( i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
            if (buffer[i] == '\0') {
                buffer[i] = '@';
                // optionally, i += 64; since
                // "Once you've found a null byte, it's also guaranteed that there can't
                // be another one for a hundred bytes or so"
            }
        }
        write(1, buffer, size);
    }
}
```

Naturally, compile with optimizations so that the compiler can transform indexing into pointer arithmetic if helpful.

This version also lends itself well to SIMD optimizations if you still aren't meeting your speed targets (or a smart enough compiler may vectorize the `for` loop automatically).

Furthermore, this code lacks robust error handling.  As @chqrlie mentions in a comment, you should retry when you get `-EINTR`, and you should handle partial writes.

Comment: `689MiB/s`! Really didn't expect `stdio`'s buffering to have so much overhead. Thanks. :)

Comment: This approach is tricky:  `read` can return `-1` if it was interrupted by a signal and it should be restarted. `write(1, buffer, size);` may return a smaller count for various reasons, and `-1` for the same reason as `read`, it should then be restarted.  Failing to handle this corner cases will produce hard to find bugs in production, usually at the worst moment...  Using the `stdio.h` functions is much safer and not much slower: use `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: @chqrlie: Already fixed.  And I believe that `fwrite` suffers from the same problems as `write`.  I'll add a note to that effect.

Comment: C11 7.21.8.2: *The `fwrite` function returns the number of elements successfully written, which will be less than `nmemb` only if a write error is encountered.*  I don't think the signal is considered a write error, only actual write errors and out of space.  Handling partial writes is still recommended and not very difficult nor costly.

Comment: @Dougal: It's not so much the buffering; reading one byte at a time, you have to call a function for each byte you read. If you read a block at a time, you're making 1/16384 as many function calls (in this example).

Comment: @cHao: using the `_unlocked` versions of `getchar()` and `putchar()` usually converts these function calls to inline macro expansions.  Using `fread` / `fwrite` removes extra checks for buffer limits.

Comment: You can combine the 2 tests in the loop by making the buffer one byte larger and setting a '\0' at the end.  You then only need to test the position on matches, effectively dividing the number of tests by 2.

Comment: @Andrew Henle: true but give the buffer size, `int` is large enough.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is incorrect because you do not test for end of file at the right spot.  It is a **very** common mistake in `do {} while` loops.  I recommend to avoid this construct completely (except in macros to convert sequences of statements into a single statement).

Also try and tell the glibc to perform fewer checks on the stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar_unlocked()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\0')
            c = '@':
        putchar_unlocked(c);
    }
}
```

You can also play with different buffer sizes, for example try these before the `while()` loop:

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024 * 1024);
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024 * 1024);
```

It should not have much impact if you use the utility as a filter with pipes, but it may be more efficient if you use files.

If you use files, you can also `mmap` the file and use `memchr` to find the `'\0'` bytes, or even `strchr` that might be faster and you can ensure there is a `'\0`` at the end of the file (putting it there is a good way).

Comment: Oh, good catch with the check; shouldn't really be relevant to the processing speed, though.

Comment: Using the `_unlocked` functions doubles the speed, up to 16.5ish MiB/sec. Halfway there! :)

Comment: @Dougal: Try increasing the buffer size

Comment: `1024*1024` didn't help; 10 times that slowed it down slightly.

Comment: As noted in the question, I can't really use a raw file because the input is gzipped, and going to disk first would probably defeat the point.

Answer (score 0):

First, as others have noted, don't use `getchar()/putchar()`, or even any of the FILE-based methods such as `fopen()/fread()/fwrite()`.  Use `open()/read()/write()` instead.

If the file is already uncompressed on disk, do not use pipes.  If it is compressed, then you DO want to use a pipe in order remove an entire read/write cycle.  If you uncompress from disk back to disk, then replace the NUL characters, the data path is disk->memory/cpu->disk->memory/cpu->disk.  If you use a pipe, the path is disk->memory/cpu->disk.  If you're disk-limited, that extra read/write cycle will just about double the time it takes to process your gigabytes (or more) of data.

One more thing - given your IO pattern and the amount of data your moving - read an entire multi-GB file, write the entire file - the page cache is only getting in your way.  Use direct IO, thusly in C on Linux (headers and robust error checking left off for clarity):

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE ( 1024UL * 1024UL * 4UL )
#define NEW_CHAR '@'
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    /* page-aligned buffer */
    char *buf = valloc( CHUNK_SIZE );
    /* just set "in = 0" to read a stdin pipe */
    int in = open( argv[ 1 ], O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT );
    int out = open( argv[ 2 ], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_DIRECT, 0644 );

    for ( ;; )
    {
        ssize_t bytes = read( in, buf, CHUNK_SIZE );
        if ( bytes < 0 )
        {
            if ( errno == EINTR )
            {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if ( bytes == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }

        for ( int ii = 0; ii < bytes; ii++ )
        {
            if ( !buf[ ii ] )
            {
                buf[ ii ] = NEW_CHAR;
            }
        }
        write( out, buf, bytes );
    }

    close( in );
    close( out );

    return( 0 );
}
```

Crank up the compiler optimization as high as it goes.  To use this code on real data, you do need to check the results of the `write()` call - direct IO on Linux is a real finicky beast.  I've had to close a file opened with O_DIRECT and reopen a it without direct IO set in order to write the last bytes of a file on Linux when the last bits weren't a multiple of a full page.

If you want to go even faster, you can multithread the process - one thread reads, one thread translates chars, and another thread writes.  Use as many buffers, passing them from thread to thread, as necessary to keep the slowest part of the process busy at all times.

If you're really interested in seeing how fast you can move data, multithread the reads/writes, too.  And if your filesystem support it, use asynchronous read/write.

Comment: That's a lot of suggestions, but it does not well serve the OPs problem: He uses pipes, so the API is inappropriate and the huge buffer is useless.  Error handling is absent (good for clarity, but bad for results), especially trying to `write` -1 bytes is calling for trouble. Multithreading read, translate and write phases or using asynchronous I/O is not for the faint of heart, it goes well beyond reasonable effort to reduce the bottleneck.

Comment: Yet another good illustration of how `do {} while` loops are mostly broken.

Comment: And your experience moving petabytes of data or doing IO on high-performance storage is?  Well, it's obviously zero else you would never even think of calling 4 MB "huge" or "useless".  Do you really think multithreading and async IO are really "not for the faint of heart"?  I guess we just work and code in different worlds.

Comment: I am stating facts, 4MB is vastly larger than the pipe buffer, it does not help at all, the OP verified it.  `mmap` would be a good way to get closer to the metal, but it is a little tricky for huge files.  using a different thread for reading, translating and writing in this particular case is hardly useful and not so trivial.  You seem to master the art, give it a try and see what multiple you get.  You retaliating on the accepted answer shows little respect for actual results.

Comment: The fact that 4MB is vastly larger than the pipe buffer isn't going to hurt performance on `read()`.  And when accessing a fast disk system - which the OPs SSD could very well be - the larger buffer will improve performance.  Try it - get a disk system that can sustain reads and writes at a GB/sec or more.  The OP's "verification" consisted of changing the buffer used for `fopen()/fread()/fwrite()`. That does not apply to any performance differences that may arise in `read()/write()` calls doing direct IO when using a different-sized buffer. `ii` being a size_t only matters with a >2GB buffer.

Comment: A buffer 2GB or larger **is** too big - it can put extreme memory pressure on the machine, never mind that it won't work at all for a process with an ILP32 memory model.  And doing 64-bit math when 32 bit ones suffice could slow things down.

Comment: I agree that a large buffer will probably improve the performance for file based I/O.  The `O_DIRECT` flag is a good hint too! Handcrafting the loop gets another 50% increase from the OPs timings.  Make `ii` and `bytes` the same type for consistency, `int` is fine of course for any decent size buffer ;-)

Comment: Depending on your I/O subsystem, doing really large sequential reads and then really large sequential writes will reduce disk seeks (compared with trying to stream both at once).  Also, create mode should be `0666`.  That's what `umask` is for: to give the user the option of which other/group bits they want to mask off.

Comment: Also, instead of rewriting in place, it might be best to copy while scanning and hand the new page off to the kernel with `vmsplice`.  Otherwise your write buffer has to be copied into the page cache.  OTOH, that would mean you'd have to allocate a new buffer, and probably suffer TLB and cache misses while writing it.

Comment: @PeterCordes `sendfile()` is another option - one that would avoid copying the file data into and out of user space entirely.

Comment: That doesn't let you modify it, though